# R markdown page number in citations

Tags: r, r-markdown, citations

How can I get "p." before the page number in R markdown citations? I followed the [markdown documentation](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html)

but [@Cochrane.2011, p. 1058] returns (Cochrane 2011, 1058). 
But I am looking for (Cochrane 2011, p. 1058)

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you will have to define your citation style

Comment: I'm not familiar with setting up the styling, but there's some explanation under "citation styles" at the documentation you linked to

Answer (score 4):

thanks @slava-kohut, setting the citation style to e.g. `csl: apa.csl` did the trick